# Using element "unless" for @Cacheable [spring 3.2.3] not working

Tags: spring, caching

I did use `unless` following for Cacheable, but it seems it did not work.
For the function below, it still will cache the result if result = -1.

Not sure what is the reason for its not working. Anyone gets any ideas? Any lib missing?

```
@Cacheable(value="queueIds", key="#servicePhoneNumber", unless="#result == -1")
public int getQueueIdByPhoneNumber(String servicePhoneNumber) { ... }
```

Comment: How are you verifying that the method is invoked twice? Can you share some details about what the cache configuration looks like, some test code, etc?

Comment: @mattb Are you saying how to verify the info was cached? Actually you could add logger to record that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The problem is that I used two different spring versions in a project.

Comment: Yeah, I removed duplicated library. But maybe your issue is different, just symptoms are the same